# How to assign existing textboxes to textbox array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox, assign

I have 30 existing textboxes (TextBox... TextBox30) in a c# web app (not winform), I would like to create an array.

```
TextBox[] tb = new TextBox[30];
```

Then assign all 30 existing buttons to that array.

Is there a faster way to do it than adding one by one?

```
tb[0]=TextBox1;
```

Comment: Well, you can create them dynamically instead of manually

Answer (score 0):

```
TextBox[] tb = { TextBox1, TextBox2, ... };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try not to be lazy, but just wondering if there is a way to add it in a for loop? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can if you know how many textboxes are. If you don't, then you can't. An array must have a fixed length. You can use a List, though.

Comment: Yes, I know, there are 30 testboxes, I tried to use Controls.Add, but it didn't work, please advise.

Comment: If they're sequential and all have the same parent control or page, you can probably do something like `var tb = Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => Page.FindControl("TextBox" + i) as TextBox).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

possibly might be able to help:

```
var txtBox = Form1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();

for(i = 0; i < txtBox.Count; i++)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

My syntax might be a little off...

Comment: I use this kind of method to simulate a `SelectedIndex()` for a groupbox of radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer tp use `list` instead of `array` because I am more lazy.

```
        List<TextBox> txtBoxs = new List<TextBox>();

        foreach (Control ctl in splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls){

            TextBox txtBox = ctl as TextBox;

            if (txtBox != null)
            {
                txtBoxs.Add(txtBox);
            }

        }
```